# Error in accessing a 2D array inside a class

Tags: c++, static, constants, multidimensional-array

I have been working on a code in C++. But, I got stuck at a point.

This is a small prototype of my code::

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
private:
    const int var;
    void funPrivate(int arr[][var], int temp){
        cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
    }
public:
    Test(int n) : var(n){};

    void funPublic(){
        int a[var][var];
        funPrivate(a, var);
      cout << "Hello";
    };
};

int main()
{
    Test t1(5);
    t1.funPublic();
    return 0;
}
```

I create a class `funPublic()` method, where I create a 2D array (using the const int var, which I declare as a private member inside my class `Test`) and then pass it to a private methode `funPrivate(int arr[][var], int temp)`, where I print `arr[0][0]` (which shall be a garbage value).

But, when I try to run this program, I get an error::

`error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Test::var'`

My method `funPrivate(int arr[][var], int temp)` is a normal function (not a static function) and I don't a reason that I shall declare `int var` as static. Why does this happen.

Further, if I slightly modify the declaration of my method 'funPrivate(int arr[][var], int temp)' to this `void funPrivate(int arr[][var])` then I get one more error:

`error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope`

Now, I don't know why does that happen. We pass the size of the array for our convenience, because there is no way to determine the size of the array in a function, but that shall not cause the error that `arr was not declared in this scope`.

I have been thinking and searching a lot, but still can't find an answer. Please help. Thanks for any help in advance. :D

Comment: `var` needs to be know at compile time since it is used as an array dimensions.  You can use `int**` if you don't know what the dimensions will be at compile time.

Comment: Yes, but I am not dynamically allocating my array. And I need to pass the second dimension of the array to make it work, I believe.

Comment: Btw, you can find out the value of var because the size of an array element must be known at compile time (and that's why your code doesn't compile -- there's const and there's const). var is sizeof(a[0])/sizeof(a[0][0]). Provided the array contains at least one element with at least one element.

Comment: @PeterSchneider But, the array is getting declared. There is no problem with the declaration of the array. If I do not call the `funPrivate()` the code works fine. (having declared it as a constant, that is a valid statement I believe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member variable `var` cannot be used in the declaration of an array like you are attempting in the function `funPrivate`:

```
void funPrivate(int arr[][var], int temp)
```

Your best option is to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

```
void funPrivate(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& arr, int temp) {
    cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
}
```

In the calling function, you can use:

```
void funPublic(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(var, std::vector<int>(var));
    funPrivate(arr, var);
   cout << "Hello";
};
```

Comment: Getting an error, I do know that I cannot use this statement (Not to be taken rudely ;) ) But sir, why I cannot use that?? And the error that the compiler gives me is not that I cannot use that declaration, but the error is that it shall be `static`

Comment: @user007: Because types are a compile-time feature, yet you are attempting to make the type of your array (remember: the dimension is part of the type!) dependent on a runtime value. It doesn't matter that it's marked `const`: it's still a runtime value. It cannot define array bounds.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit
 But, then how does this work fine?? :\ http://ideone.com/hmYf0f 
And, but `type` do you mean the function prototype?? You mean the data type of the variable `var` right??

Comment: @user007, in that case, the value of `temp` is known at compile time.

Comment: @RSahu I wrote this small code :: http://ideone.com/Uejks9
I don't know but this works fine on my CodeBlocks IDE, but gives a runtime error on ideone. :\
But, I don't get it is the declaration of the array faulty?? (But, had the declaration of the array been faulty this won't have worked :: http://ideone.com/iigSAr
And, if the declaration of the function is faulty then what is the reason for this? There are too many contradicting things around. :\

Comment: @user007 The reason why it compiles is that by default, ideone uses an extension that exists in the g++ compiler.  If you were to compile this using the `-Wall -pedantic` switch, you will receive the compiler error others have already mentioned.  In other words, your code that compiles is not standard C++.